Random select from mobile filtered list
I would like to do a sendout for a random group of people (e.g. 10 000 out of 100 000). Is there any way to do such a random selection in the Mobile Filtered List?
The only way, which comes to my mind, is to use the Mobile Filtered Group as an audience in the journey and use there a random split, but I don't think it's optimized way, as the journey will process all the 100 000 contacts).
Any help would be appreciated!

You can export the Mobile Filtered list and then import it into a Data Extension.
From there, you can split it to a target data extension so you can use it in the journey with random record rows.
You can use create a random data extension type in email studio for this.
Or just make a SQL query to split it, sample SQL:
SELECT TOP 10000
SubscriberKey,
MobileNumber,
Locale
FROM
[your mobile filtered list DE]
ORDER BY newid()

